# Can I install Unison for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: sync, unison

I have two machines running Ubuntu. One runs Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and the other one runs Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I want to use *unison* to sync files between them. I've installed *unison* on both of them the conventional way. I.e.:

```
sudo apt install unison-all
```

When I check what version is installed, I get this on both machines:

```
unison version 2.48.4
```

When I try to sync between them, the sync fails and I get the message:

> Fatal error during unmarshaling (input value:ill-formed message)
>   possibly because client and serer have been compiled with different
>   versions of OCaml compiler.

When I look at `/usr/bin/unison-2.48.4` on both machines, I get:

```
3377264 Oct 31  2017 /usr/bin/unison-2.48.4 [18.04]
3866920 Feb 16 10:04 /usr/bin/unison-2.48.4 [20.04]
```

So while the version number is the same, they have different sizes and a different timestamps, and my guess is that the difference is what causing the error.

The problem is also posted here: https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5750379.html – but no solution yet.

The *unison* that is installed on the machine running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS syncs fine with *unison* 2.48.4 for MS Windows 10, so that is the one I want to use on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as well.

Is there any way to install the version of *unison* available for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Unison 20.04 LTS?

If "yes", how?

Comment: Did you try to downlad and install from here? https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=unison&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all I guess you'll have dependencies errors, though...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think a better solution is

1. Purge the current installation
2. Install the former Debian version on the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server:

```
wget http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/u/unison/unison_2.48.4-1+b1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i unison_2.48.4-1+b1_amd64.deb
```

```
wget http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/u/unison/unison-gtk_2.48.4-1+b1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i unison-gtk_2.48.4-1+b1_amd64.deb
```

Then set them on hold `aptitude hold unison unison-gtk`.
Follow https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unison/+bug/1875475 to see when it will be fixed.

Comment: I am using this as well, and it works well. Three comments
1. I now use the Ubuntu 18.04 package rather than Debian one: `wget http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/u/unison/unison_2.48.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i unison_2.48.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb`
2. `aptitude hold unison` is mandatory... otherwise after a few days you get the 2.48.4-4 version back
3. It did not work completely until I removed the unison archives (`ar...` and `fp...` files) generated by the 2.48.4-4 version in `~/.unison`.

Comment: You only have to delete the `fp...`, thankfully. I don't know what that one does, but the ar should track what's updated and not, so luckily it seems to have not caused too many issues.

Comment: Works with unison 2.40.102-2ubuntu1 too for me from here http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/u/unison/ because I needed an older version.

Answer (score 8):

I've discovered the hard way what apparently is common knowledge: *Unison* is extremely picky about not only the version number of the tool itself, but also the OCaml compiler used to compile it.  It looks like the team that put together the binaries for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS *recompiled* with a *newer* version of the OCaml compiler than what was previously used, without thinking about backwards and cross-platform compatibility is the *main* feature of syncing tool. IMHO, that's a major goof-up.

The way I fixed this was to first purge *unison* on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS via *apt* and
then reinstalling it "by hand" by using the static file `unison-2.48.4-linux-i386-text-static.tar.gz`that can be downloaded from: https://www.urs-mueller.ch/de/computer/index.html.

I am not an Ubuntu wizard, so I don't know if that is the *correct* way to go about this, but it works for me and allows me to sync between all my computers again.

Comment: Yeah, this is the way I've had to do it too. Except I'm running with version 2.40.63 because that's what the folks at [rsync.net](https://www.rsync.net/) have running on their sync servers.

Comment: It's much easier this way. I wrote at script at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233504/how-to-use-multiple-versions-of-unison-on-one-system/771980#771980 . Note that the releases are on GitHub now: https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/releases

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, better in the long run IMHO, especially if you are synchronizing only linux machines, would be to install the snap version of Unison.

This version of Unison is system independent and whatever version of Ubuntu, Debian, etc. you install it on, it is always compiled against the same OCaml. So you don't have to worry about these issues every time something changes in Unison or OCaml. Currently, Unison is at 2.51.2 and OCaml 4.02.3

See this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583058/unison-and-version-compiler-conflicts/583377#583377

Remember that you must install snapd first if you are not using Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```

Log out and back in again, or restart your system, to ensure snap’s paths are updated correctly before proceeding.

Then, follow the steps showed in either the link above or this one:

http://www.xente.mundo-r.com/zasjls/other/20/unison_en.html

Comment: When you install using snaps than all paths outside home won't be accessible. So I could not sync my Media-Library which has a couple of terras.

Comment: @wstein Have you tried installing unison in developer mode


`sudo snap install --devmode unison-jz`

Comment: @zasjis Not installed in dev mode but set it to dev mode after install. Hope this answered your question